# Заполнение текстовых полей

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать проверку, чтобы если три текстовых поля не пустые, то в 4 что то писалось. Например, пользователь вводит в трех текстовых полях по символу и программа сразу после ввода символа в третьем поле выдает определенную запись в четвертом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    // ....
});
```

Comment: У меня ругается на getDocument() и DocumentListener(), пишет cannot find symbol.

Comment: ну всеравно надо на поле по вешать листенер, посмотри какие есть у swing-а, что-то из .addActionListener(new ...)

Comment: Никак не могу реализовать прослушиватель для текстового поля, чтобы происходили какие то действия когда текст менялся в текстовом поле. Уже разные способы перепробовал,получается только после нажатия кнопки.

Comment: используешь JTextField? замени на JFormattedTextField

Comment: а без swinga нельзя это реализовать?

Comment: т.е awt или чем ты пользуешься? можно наверное, я не знаю что ты делаешь

Comment: ну вот такой пример,хочу чтобы когда пользователь водил что то в одно текстовое поле,этот текст сразу же появлялся по мере поступления в другом текстовом поле.